# Candidate Elimination Algorithm - special situation

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing a question on Candidate Elimination Algorithm. 
I am a little confused with the general boundary G.

Here is an example, I got G and S to the fourth training example, but I am not sure with the last case.

1. Sunny,Warm,Normal,Strong,Warm,Same,EnjoySport=yes
2. Sunny,Warm,High,Strong,Warm,Same,EnjoySport=yes
3. Rainy,Cold,High,Strong,Warm,Change,EnjoySport=no
4. Sunny,Warm,High,Strong,Cool,Change,EnjoySport=yes
5. Sunny,Warm,Normal,Weak,Warm,Same,EnjoySport=no

What I have here is : 
S0: `{<0,0,0,0,0,0>}`

S1: `{<Sunny,Warm,Normal,Strong,Warm,Same>}`

S2, S3: `{<Sunny,Warm,?,Strong,Warm,Same>}`

S4: `{<Sunny,Warm,?,Strong,?,?>}`

G4: `{<Sunny,?,?,?,?,?>, <?,Warm,?,?,?,?>}`

G3: `{<Sunny,?,?,?,?,?>, <?,Warm,?,?,?,?>, <?,?,?,?,?,Same>}`

G0, G1 ,G2 : `{<?,?,?,?,?,?>}`

What would be the result of G5? 
Is it G5 empty? `{}` or `{<?,?,?,Strong,?,?>}`?

Thanks

Comment: This is straight from the text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G5 is neither of those.

Note that {???Strong??} is not a specialisation of G4, so that's not a valid addition to the general boundary.

Rather, you would remove {Sunny,?,?,?,?,?} and {?,Warm,?,?,?,?} and replace them with minimal specialisations of each. So in this case, you would end up with:

G5 = {Sunny,?,High,?,?,?}, {Sunny,?,?,Strong,?,?}, {?,Warm,High,?,?,?}, {?,Warm,?,Strong,?,?}.

Comment: I don't understand, for example {Sunny,?,High,?,?,?}, how can third attribute be "High" when it was "?" in S set?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that G5 is equal to {?,Warm,?,Strong,?,?}, {Sunny,?,?,Strong,?,?}
That means that  {Sunny,?,High,?,?,?} and {?,Warm,High,?,?,?} are not part of G. Why? BEacuse you can look at example nr.1 - it is not classified as positive by {Sunny,?,High,?,?,?} and {?,Warm,High,?,?,?}.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Rich is wrong.

`<Sunny,?,High,?,?,?>` and `<?,Warm,High,?,?,?>` are not generalisation of   `<Sunny,Warm,?,Strong,?,?>` (the only hypothesis in *S4*).

The **correct answer** should be

G5: `{<Sunny,?,?,Strong,?,?>, <?,Warm,?,Strong,?,?>}`

---

According to the Candidate Elimination algorithm, when encountering a negative training example *d*, for each hypothesis *g* in general hypothesis set *G* that is not consistent with the example:

1. Remove *g* from *G*.
2. Add to *G* all minimal specialisations *h* of *g*, such that *h* is consistent with *d*, and **some member of *S* is more specific than *h*.**
3. Remove from *G* any hypothesis that is less general than another hypothesis in *G*.